# Page not found even when JsonResult method is present

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I am working in an MVC application and I am getting 404 error when calling a JsonResult AJAXly

**My request:**

```
http://localhost:60890/ED/Document/GetGroupDocumentMergedPath?groupDocuments=%5B%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A1314%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A212%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A149%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A208%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A570%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A210%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A198%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A209%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A90%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A201%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A119%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A206%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A2431%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A217%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A1004%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A211%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A1686%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A213%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A2076%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A215%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A2469%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A302%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A5140%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A220%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A5020%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A221%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A5105%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A222%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A5066%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A223%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4039%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A225%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4159%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A235%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4283%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A245%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4343%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A249%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4399%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A250%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4463%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A252%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4856%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A256%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4906%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A257%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A4956%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A258%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22GroupDocumentId%22%3A2499%2C%22TemplateId%22%3A215%2C%22GroupDocumentType%22%3A0%7D%5D&actionType=715&_=1456902108180
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult GetGroupDocumentMergedPath(string groupDocuments, int actionType){}
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ED/Document/GetGroupDocumentMergedPath',
    type: "GET",
    data: { groupDocuments: JSON.stringify(groupDocuments), actionType: 715 },
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //Business logic
    },
    complete: function () {
        checkedIds = {};
        ToggleDisabled("print", false);
    }
});
```

**Scenario:**

In the AJAX call I am sending a list of, on average, 20 objects with three properties.

I the query string length is longer than the allowed causing the error or where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it working if you use just (say) `data: { groupDocuments: 'abc', actionType: 715 },`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke IF the load is less it's working, here I am trying to download a group of documents, when I do for a single document (where only one object in the list) it's working fine

Comment: Because its a GET, you probably exceeding the query string limit. Try making it a POST instead BUt why are you posting it as a string - you should be posting objects and the parameter should be (say) `List<yourModel> documents`

Comment: @StephenMuecke with List<> we don't have any limit?

Comment: Not when you use `type: "Post",`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll change it to Post as well as receive it as List<> and update you, thanks for the tip

Comment: @RandomUser when sending data, the GET method adds the data to the URL; and the length of a URL is limited (maximum URL length is `2048 characters`).

Comment: You will need to make a few changes to the ajax - add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and change `data JSON.stringfy({ groupDocuments: groupDocuments, actionType: 715 }),` assuming `groupDocuments` is an array of your objects.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked will answer the question with the changes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass multiple detail in single string. you have to create One ViewModel and pass to serializeObject of model in Data. so it's safe and good way to pass data via AJAX to Method.

if you want to pass data from form control then serialize form and pass it AJAX.

Please check out below example. 
Ajax call

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
    form = $('#groupDocuments').serializeObject(); // groupDocuments is form Id
    var data = JSON.stringify({ model: form });    
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ED/Document/GetGroupDocumentMergedPath',
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //Business logic
        },
        complete: function () {
            checkedIds = {};
            ToggleDisabled("print", false);
        }
    });
```

JasonResult Method

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetGroupDocumentMergedPath(GroupDocumentViewModel model)
    {
    // Your Code here       
    }
```

view Model

```
public class GroupDocumentViewModel
{   
//All your property which you passing from view to controller via AJAX  
}
```